# Override base empty.xml file to rename the page-wrapper class

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3

I am creating a magento theme based on the magento/blank theme, and I am trying to change the opening div's class from page-wrapper to container.

**Attempt**
I tried to create a file in `/app/code/myvendor/theme/Theme/view/layout/override/base/empty.xml` with the intention it would replace the file in `/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml` allowing me to change the class but nothing happened.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>
        <container name="page.wrapper" as="page_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
            <container name="global.notices" as="global_notices" before="-"/>
            <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">
                <container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>
                <container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
                    <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="page.bottom.container" as="page_bottom_container" label="Before Page Footer Container" after="main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-bottom"/>
            <container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</layout>
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to overrider xml file inside your custom theme to make effect of changes

Comment: Your path is wrong if you want to override into theme then your file location should be `app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/view/layout/override/base/empty.xml`

Comment: @ManthanDave Thanks, I have just tried creating a file: /app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/view/layout/override/base/empty.xml with the same contents as what I put above, but the class isnt changing on the website. The only way so far I have managed to achieve this is by editing the original base file in Magento's files which of course is bad practise. Any more ideas?

Comment: @LeonHunter you have created custom theme right ? so first verify that your custom theme is active or not ? you don't need to edit base file.

Comment: @ManthanDave yes, I have created the theme and can verify it is working, I have replaced the theme logo using a different xml file (layout.xml)

Comment: @LeonHunter yes then just change your file location on this place - `app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/view/frontend/lay‌​out/page_layout/empty.xml`  and then try to override it . it will works. after that clean the cache

Comment: @ManthanDave Just tried creating the file in the location you suggested and clearing the cache and it didn't update the class, its as if this file is being totally ignored by magento?

Comment: @LeonHunter check my answer on the below . put your file on given location and it will works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just placed the empty.xml in the following location and it worked:

**app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/empty.xml**

Comment: I can't replicate the solution. I change the theme in the admin. I can confirm other changes do apply, like the less/css changes. I tried all the posible options in this page. Here a list of files I'v tested (they all inside my theme folder)

- ./Magento_Theme/view/layout/override/base/empty.xml
- ./Magento_Theme/view/layout/base/empty.xml
- ./Magento_Theme/view/frontend/layout/page_layout/empty.xml
- ./Magento_Theme/view/frontend/page_layout/empty.xml
- ./Magento_Theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml
- ./Magento_Theme/page_layout/empty.xml

But none of them worked.

Comment: 2.3 = /app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<module>/Magento_Theme/page_layout/empty.xml

Answer (score 1):

you have to keep your content at below location,

> app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/view/frontend/page_layout/empty.xml

now add your code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>
        <container name="page.wrapper" as="page_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
            <container name="global.notices" as="global_notices" before="-"/>
            <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">
                <container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>
                <container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
                    <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="page.bottom.container" as="page_bottom_container" label="Before Page Footer Container" after="main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-bottom"/>
            <container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</layout>
```

Run `php bin/magento cache:clean` command

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have just tried creating /app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/view/frontend/layout/page_layout/empty.xml but it is still not changing the page. Its like this file is being ignored by the system?

Comment: Have you clean cache? also clear browser cache.

Comment: yeah I just cleaned Magento cache using php bin/magento cache:clean and also my browser cache and the changes still don't take affect.

Comment: you have to give below location, app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/view/fro‌​ntend/page_la‌​yout/empty.xml  remove layout folder. Its typomistake for layout folder

Comment: Have you check using remove layout folder from Magento_Theme/page_layout?

Comment: Yeah, currently I have a file in /app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/view/base/page_layout called empty.xml, cleared the cache and no luck! I have no idea why this isnt working!

Comment: instead of base you can keep file inside Magento_Theme/view/frontend folder and check

Comment: Tried remove base and using the path you said (Magento_Theme/view/frontend) that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this, I faced the same issue for updating empty.xml file from Magento_Theme/view/base/page_layout.

I have created a custom layout inside my `/<vendor>/<theme>/<Magento_Theme>/layouts.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="custom-layout">
        <label translate="true">Custom Layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

Then I have created a layout file inside `/<vendor>/<theme>/<Magento_Theme>/page_layout/custom-layout.xml`

Then I have update the update handler like this

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="custom"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Then I have create a `custom.xml` file inside same folder `/<vendor>/<theme>/<Magento_Theme>/page_layout/custom.xml`

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>
        <container name="page.wrapper" as="page_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-wrapper">
            <container name="global.notices" as="global_notices" before="-"/>
            <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="mycontent" htmlClass="mycontent">
                <container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>
                <container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mycontent">
                    <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mycontent"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="page.bottom.container" as="page_bottom_container" label="Before Page Footer Container" after="main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-bottom"/>
            <container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</layout>
```

Now I am able to update base layout file as I want.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

okay so you have issue with the location.

You are overriding directly view not layout. so your file location should be below :

**app/design/frontend/myvendor/theme/Magento_Theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml**

Then add your code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>
        <container name="page.wrapper" as="page_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
            <container name="global.notices" as="global_notices" before="-"/>
            <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">
                <container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>
                <container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
                    <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="page.bottom.container" as="page_bottom_container" label="Before Page Footer Container" after="main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-bottom"/>
            <container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</layout>
```

**Clear the cache and check it will works !!**

Comment: Cleared the cache and tried putting the file in app/design/frontend/myvendor/theme/Magento_Theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml and still not working.

Comment: 2.3 = /app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<module>/Magento_Theme/page_layout/empty.xml