# Override empty.xml in a custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.2.6, custom-theme

I'm creating a new theme for a Magento 2.2.6 community edition and I need to wrap all the content inside a CSS class. To do so I had to change

```
<main id="maincontent" class="page-main">
```

to

```
<main id="maincontent" class="page-main myCustomWrapper">
```

To do that. I understand I need to change the line

```
<container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">
```

in the in the empty.xml file to

```
<container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main myCustomWrapper">
```

I've tested that in the vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml file and it worked. I then reverted and tried copying it to my theme. I followed the instructions here: [Override base empty.xml file to rename the page-wrapper class](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159597/override-base-empty-xml-file-to-rename-the-page-wrapper-class) and tried all possible combinations I could think about. Here the list of the files I tried:

- Magento_Theme/view/layout/override/base/empty.xml
- Magento_Theme/view/layout/base/empty.xml
- Magento_Theme/view/frontend/layout/page_layout/empty.xml
- Magento_Theme/view/frontend/page_layout/empty.xml
- Magento_Theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml
- Magento_Theme/page_layout/empty.xml

They all inside my frontend theme, but none of the tested files worked.

**Is my frontend theme working?**

Yes. That was the first thing I tried. I changed it int the backend/admin, I changed the Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml and changes were shown in my site, so the theme does work.

**Did I clean cache?**

Yes, before refreshing the page, I did clean the cache and remove all files in pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/ var/di/* var/generation/* after every change in all the possible */empty.xml.

I asked in the freenode channel, I looked in the magento stackexchange site, but nothing.

Any hints will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can override "empty.xml" in a custom module. Just put it in `app/code/<Vendor>/<module>/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml`

Comment: 2.3 = /app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<module>/Magento_Theme/page_layout/empty.xml